# Download dependencies from maven repository manually

Tags: maven

I don't have maven installed and I'd rather not try to learn yet another tool. But I do need to use an API that provides only a link to a maven repository in its documentation:

```
maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
```

Since maven seems to work over standard HTTP, is there a way I can manually download the needed files from the repository just using my web browser? It's probably just one or two `.jar` files, but I just can't "guess" the right link...

I've spent quite some time searching for an answer, but I can't even find documentation on the file structure of a maven repository.

Comment: Seems like you need some version information in order to come up with the full url.  I was able to pull the maven-jetty-plubin version 6.0.0 by browsing Maven Central and utlimately ended up @ http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/mortbay/jetty/maven-jetty-plugin/6.0.0/  It is just standard https.

Comment: Maven is easy to install and easy to use IMO BTW.

Answer (score 0):

The Maven repository layout is described in the [Maven 2.0 Design Documents](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVENOLD/Repository+Layout+-+Final):

> For primary artifacts:
>
> ```
> /$groupId[0]/../${groupId[n]/$artifactId/$version/$artifactId-$version.$extension
> ```
>
> For secondary artifacts:
>
> ```
> /$groupId[0]/../$groupId[n]/$artifactId/$version/$artifactId-$version-$classifier.$extension
> ```

What does it mean? Every artifact is described by an identifier which is built from: group id, artifact id, version and optionally classifier and packaging. The tool which you want to use is probably described by something like (Maven example)

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>group.id</groupId>
    <artifactId>artifact.id</artifactId>
    <version>version</version>
    <classifier>abc</classifier> <!-- optional -->
    <packaging>zip</packaging> <!-- optional -->
</dependency>
```

or (Gradle example)

```
implementation 'group.id:artifact.id:version:abc@zip'
```

By using this information you can build URLs. I'll use the server URL which you used in the question:

```
https://maven.fabric.io/public/group/id/artifact.id/version/artifact.id-version-abc.zip
```

Every dot (`.`) in the group id is replaced by the slash character (`/`).

As you wrote you need some `.jar` files, so links will be probably in this format:

```
https://maven.fabric.io/public/group/id/artifact.id/version/artifact.id-version.jar
```